# Compile and Deploy the Selected Modules in java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, architecture, jboss

In my application I have three java modules. I have to deploy it into the tomcat server dynamically by selecting module 1 and module 2 or module 3. The selected modules will gets packaged and form a war file and gets deployed in server without restarting. How can I achieve this? Is there any Apache products/tools or any  available to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products/tools you should look at is the [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html). The default installation of Tomcat comes with the Tomcat Manager. As the names says it can manage (deploy, undeploy, reload, start, stop) applications for Tomcat without reastart. I'm not realy sure what are your needs and how your precondition look like, but i see four ways how you may can do this:

1. If you already have a WAR, you can simply use the Tomcat-Manager via a Browser. Just call the manager URL (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`). There you have options to upload a WAR and undeploy a application. (Before you can login, you have to edit tomcat-users.xml - just google a bit).
2. Use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Ant is a XML-based build tool for Java. With Ant you can compile your SourceCode and pack it into a WAR. If you tomcat runs local, you can copy the WAR via ant in the webapps directory of the Tomcat. Tomcat will auto-deploy it (if auto-deploy is active, as it is by default). And if you remove one WAR from webapps, tomcat will auto undeploy.
3. Tomcat provides a library with ant commands, to deploy the WAR via HTTP over Tomcat-Manager to the server ([Tomcat Ant Commands](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant)). So if the tomcat is remote, use this command via ant.
4. You don't like Ant? Use the Tomcat Manager direct via HTTP. ([HTTP Commands](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands)). Of course than you have to compile and build the WAR on your own.

I hope it is usefull for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my requirement I have three module, I want to select any of two modules. For eg: Login, Save Modules. Now this modules will be combined together to form a war file, Which should be deployed in server.(The concept here is only selected features/modules should be compiled). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest to use Ant to build the WAR, depending on you selection. If the server is locale on the maschine where you build the WAR, use way "2". If the server is remote, use way "3".  A detailed tutorial would be to much to post it here, especially there are many tutorials out there. Like [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-to-tomcat-using-ant.html) or [that](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_deploying_applications.htm). If you never used Ant before, it may look complicated. But it is a very usefull tool which is fast to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @VinZ. I have OSGI bundles of each modules, Could it be possible to move it to the different servers by selecting and installing.

Comment: Uh, OSGI is a system of its own... and i am not a expert in this. Sorry. :(  Maybe then the best choice is, you ask a new question with a description of your OSGI architecture?